# Clang linking error on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, linker, g++, osx-mavericks

I have a very basic C++ program which I cannot compile using `g++` on Mac OSX 10.9.3.

*Main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"

int main() {
  MyClass::MyClass obj = MyClass::MyClass();
  return 0;
}
```

*MyClass.hpp*

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  void method();
private:

};
```

*MyClass.cpp*

```cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"

using namespace MyClass;

MyClass() {

};

void method() {

};
```

To compile it I use `g++`

```
g++ main.cpp -o out
```

Here is what I get as a result :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyClass::MyClass()", referenced from:
      _main in main-2750ac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I then run `g++ main.cpp -o out -v` and get this :

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/stan/Documents/Info/Ateliers C++/Ateliers/Drawing -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.9.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/58/ch14y2yx05v7vy1yvrsmy_3m0000gn/T/main-4d20fb.o -x c++ issue/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -o out /var/folders/58/ch14y2yx05v7vy1yvrsmy_3m0000gn/T/main-4d20fb.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyClass::MyClass()", referenced from:
      _main in main-4d20fb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get stuck here.

Comment: Does it strike you as suspicious the very function being labeled in your output as an "symbol(s) not found" is in a source file, MyClass.cpp, you mention *nowhere* in your compilation command: `g++ main.cpp -o out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't compile `MyClass.cpp`. Try this:

```
g++ main.cpp MyClass.cpp -o out
```